# Как исключить файлы из коммита, чтобы включить их в другой

Tags: git

Возможно ли вернуться в состояние до коммита и сделать иначе, или как исключить файлы из коммита, чтобы включить эти файлы в другой коммит?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Да, исправить старый коммит можно следующим образом:

- создать на исправляемом коммите ветку, встать на нее (`checkout -b`)
- поправить код, залить коммит (но!) с опцией `ammend last commit` (есть
  такой переключатель в UI, и в командной строке параметр)
- все коммиты со старой ветки идущие после исправленного переместить на новую ветку (`rebase` - переместить разом,
  либо `cherry-pick` - по одному). Я предпочитаю по одному для лучшего
  разрешения конфликтов. `cherry-pick` можно так же делать из UI - правой кнопкой на коммите - и там будет такая опция.

Если вы хотите исключить из него файлы - на этапе правки кода - уберите их из коммита - "спрячьте" командой `git stash save`, `ammend last commit` чтоб перезалить текущий, `cherry-pick` до нужного коммита, в котором вы хотите файлы вставить и командой `git stash pop` вытащите их из тайника и закомитьте как надо.

Comment: счас попробую сделать `git stash` не видел в этой [книге](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2) про него пробовал так `git rm --cashed НеобходимыйФайл` не получалось.

Comment: После выполнения данной команды исключенные из коммита файлы не будут висеть как не-застейдженные изменения, а будут на "боковой спрятанной ветке".

Answer (score 12):

Самый функциональный способ, который работает без исключений вида "если это последний коммит", а подходит для любого коммита -- это команда `git rebase`.

Эта команда позволяет как угодно перекраивать коммиты: объединяя коммиты, переставляя их местами, переносить файлы из одного коммита в другой.

Культура программирования -- это не только культура написания самого кода, но в связи с широким распространением систем версионного контроля -- ещё и культура ведения разработки в VCS. В командах часто важно не только чтобы код был хорош, но и был порядок в ваших коммитах и ветках.

> Важно! Помните о том, что в большинстве команд принято делать rebase
>   только для локальных изменений, чтобы не пришлось потом выполнять `git
>   push -f`.

Итак, как исключить файлы из коммита.

Прежде всего убедитесь, что нет отслеживаемых файлов с изменениями -- иначе rebase просто не запустится.

Можете положить эти изменения в карман через `git stash`.

Если это требование выполнено -- можете запускать rebase в интерактивном режиме, например:

git rebase -i HEAD~4

После чего нужно у коммита, из которого вы хотите выделить файлы pick на edit (можно просто `e`) и выйти из редактора с сохранением изменений.

Дойдя до коммита, который отмечен буквой `e` гит остановится и будет ожидать ваших действий по изменению коммита.

Самое просто будет -- это дать команду `git reset HEAD~` и собрать в коммит все файлы (как новые, так и изменённые), за исключением тех, которые вы хотите использовать в другом коммите.

После того, как вы выполните добавление изменений через `git add` мы коммитим это как обычно через `git commit -m "message"`.

Затем оставшиеся файлы добавляем и оформляем ещё один коммит (если файлы пойдут в два коммита -- значит повторим эту операцию несколько раз)

В какой-то момент в папке не останется никаких незакоммиченных изменений -- можно взять и внести новые изменения и новые коммиты. Я часто пользуюсь этим, чтобы добавить сразу несколько коммитов после какого-то выбранного.

Когда вы решите, что сделано достаточно -- можно дать команду `git rebase --continue`. В этот момент гит начнёт добавлять все остальные коммиты, которые шли после редактируемого и если не будет конфликтов -- то будет переходить к следующему и следующему, пока не дойдёт до вашего последнего коммита. Если же конфликты будут -- их нужно будет резолвить и заново продолжать операцию `git rebase --continue`.

Я рекомендую подобные операции делать на каких-то тестовых репозиториях, чтобы попрактиковаться и не страшно было что-то сделать не так.

Для примера приведу некоторый пример выделения файлов из коммита.

---

Итак, начнём.

Допустим у нас есть такие коммиты:

```
pick 0517714 add file1.txt
pick 13ae975 add file2.txt and file3.txt
pick b967f0f add file4.txt and file5.txt
pick 412ab2d add file6.txt
```

Сделанные следующим образом:

```
$ git clone ak@localhost:aaa.git bbb
Cloning into 'bbb'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
$ cd bbb

$ touch .gitignore
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit -m "empty .gitignore"
[master (root-commit) f3f251b] empty .gitignore
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore

$ touch file1.txt
$ git add file1.txt
$ git commit -m "add file1.txt"
[master 0517714] add file1.txt
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file1.txt

$ touch file2.txt
$ git add file2.txt
$ touch file2.txt
$ touch file3.txt
$ git add file3.txt
$ git commit -m "add file2.txt and file3.txt"
[master 13ae975] add file2.txt and file3.txt
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file2.txt
 create mode 100644 file3.txt

$ touch file4.txt
$ git add file4.txt
$ touch file5.txt
$ git add file5.txt
$ git commit -m "add file4.txt and file5.txt"
[master b967f0f] add file4.txt and file5.txt
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file4.txt
 create mode 100644 file5.txt

$ touch file6.txt
$ git add file6.txt
$ git commit -m "add file6.txt"
[master 412ab2d] add file6.txt
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file6.txt
$
```

И, допустим, мы хотим перенести файл 5 в предыдущий коммит (где файлы 2 и 3).

Делаем `git rebase -i HEAD~4`:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~4
pick 0517714 add file1.txt
pick 13ae975 add file2.txt and file3.txt
pick b967f0f add file4.txt and file5.txt
pick 412ab2d add file6.txt

# Rebase f3f251b..412ab2d onto f3f251b
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
~
"~/bbb/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo" 22L, 742C
```

У коммита b967f0f заменяем pick на edit и сохраняем изменения, гит заново последовательно применяет коммиты 0517714 и 13ae975 (вы можете даже не заметить это, так быстро мелькают изменения на экране) и останаваливается на коммите b967f0f:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~4
Stopped at b967f0f... add file4.txt and file5.txt
You can amend the commit now, with

        git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

        git rebase --continue

$
```

Тут мы делаем простой шаг:

```
$ git reset HEAD~

$ git status
# HEAD detached at 13ae975
# You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on 'f3f251b'.
#   (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
#   (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       file4.txt
#       file5.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$
```

(git status просто для наглядности)

Составим новый коммит из файла 4:

```
$ clear && history -c

$ git add file4.txt
$ git commit -m "add file4.txt"
[detached HEAD 4c72f5d] add file4.txt
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file4.txt
```

Остался файл 5, создадим из него новый коммит:

```
$ git status
# HEAD detached from 13ae975
# You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on 'f3f251b'.
#   (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
#   (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       file5.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git add file5.txt
$ git commit -m "add file5.txt"
[detached HEAD f0cd810] add file5.txt
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file5.txt
$
```

После чего рабочий каталог чист и можно сказать гит, что можно продолжить операцию rebase и накатывать следующие коммиты:

```
$ git rebase --continue
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
$
```

Здесь вам не видно, между тем как вы нажали enter и перед тем, как появится надпись 'Successfully rebased' гит последовательно применит остающиеся коммиты -- в нашем случае это только коммит 412ab2d.

Вот какая у нас получилась новая история:

```
pick 0517714 add file1.txt
pick 13ae975 add file2.txt and file3.txt
pick 4c72f5d add file4.txt
pick f0cd810 add file5.txt
pick 6952a0b add file6.txt
```

Операция перестановки местами коммитов 4 и 5 и слияния коммитов 13ae975 с последующим f0cd810 тривиальна -- нужно снова дать команду rebase, переставить местами коммиты 4c72f5d  и f0cd810 и сделать squash коммита f0cd810 в коммит 13ae975 -- вот тут я писал подробнее в отдельном посте: [Можно ли в GIT добавить еще один файл в последний локальный комит?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559711/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-git-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82/559726#559726)

При помощи rebase переносить можно не только новые файлы, но изменения и удаления.

Также важно помнить, что если вы что-то неправильно сделали в середине rebase'а -- то помните, что у вас есть возможность отменить rebase: нужно дать команду `git rebase --abort`.

Comment: Отличный ответ! Немного дополню: `в большинстве команд принято делать rebase только для локальных изменений` - нередко допускается `push -f` в собственную ветку. Более того, менеджер репозиториев может поддерживать rebase и/или squash перед мержем, что по сути своей эквивалентно `rebase -i; push -f`. Пример тут: http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/gitlab_flow.html#squashing-commits-with-rebase, http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/rebase_before_merge.html

Answer (score 4):

Если это последний коммит и он находится локально, то без проблем.

Допустим, последний коммит у нас `B`, предшествующий ему коммит `A`:

1. Сбросим наш коммит командой `git reset B`.
2. Делаем `git status` и видим следующую картину:

> Последним коммитом будет коммит `A`, все изменения останутся, но они
>   будут в состоянии `not stagged`.

3. Формируем новый индекс для создания нового первого коммита с помощью команды `git add список_файлов_через_пробел` (можно каждый файл по одному добавлять).
4. Делаем `git commit -m "C"`, это будет наш первый коммит.
5. Делаем `git commit -am "D"`, это будет наш второй коммит.

Параметр `-a` - добавляет все изменённые файлы в индекс.

Альтернативные варианты шага 5:

```
git add .
git commit -m "D"
```

Или

```
git add название_файлов_через_пробел
git commit -m "D"
```

Или

```
git add название_файла_1
...
git add название_файла_N
git commit -m "D"
```