# Можно ли в GIT добавить еще один файл в последний локальный комит?

Tags: git, git-commit

У меня иногда возникает ситуация, когда забыл при коммите указать еще какой-либо файл(-ы). Можно ли как-либо в последний коммит добавить файл(-ы) ?

В Mercurial я делаю так:

1. `hg qinit`
2. Преобразовываю коммит в патч
3. Обновляю патч
4. Преобразовываю патч в коммит

Возможно есть способ и для GIT ?

Comment: ну как-бы `git add filename.blabla` и потом новый комит, переписывать историю не советую

Comment: История програмного проекта и история в привычном смысле(людей, государств) это абсолютно разные вещи! У программного проекта история совершенно по-другому устроена и пользоваться ею нужно тоже совершенно по-другому.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Да, для этого используется [опция `--amend`](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0).

**Пример использования**

1. Просмотрим историю коммитов.

   ```
   $ git log

   commit 5c4a8e76f951eb7ee157f4136257f6666fddf1d1
   Author: John Doe <johndoe@gmail.com>
   Date:   Sun Aug 28 14:40:30 2016 +0300

       Changed 1.txt

   commit 7f2ad8c26ad032800c049d0d6122c43410a5cbbc
   Author: John Doe <johndoe@gmail.com>
   Date:   Sun Aug 28 14:39:30 2016 +0300

       Initial commit
   ```
2. Допустим существует файл который нужно добавить в предыдущий коммит.

   ```
   $ git status

   On branch master
   Untracked files:
      (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)    
           test.txt
   ```
3. Добавьте этот файл в индекс при помощи команды `git add`.

   ```
   $ git add --all

   $ git status

   On branch master
   Changes to be committed:
     (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
           new file:   test.txt
   ```
4. После этого вы можете добавить файл в последний коммит посредством
   использования `--amend` в команде `git commit`. Вы можете также
   изменить сообщение коммита добавив `-m 'Commit message'`. Чтобы
   оставить сообщение коммита тем же просто передайте пустую строку
   вместо сообщения `-m ''`.

   ```
   $ git commit -m 'Added test' --amend

   [master aad3e76] Added test
    Date: Sun Aug 28 14:40:30 2016 +0300
    2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
    create mode 100644 test.txt
   ```
5. Проверим историю коммитов.

   ```
   $ git log --stat
   commit aad3e7653cd76c4afa1a9272bd421493b4e3055c
   Author: John Doe <johndoe@gmail.com>
   Date:   Sun Aug 28 14:40:30 2016 +0300

        Added test

    1.txt    | 3 ++-
    test.txt | 0
    2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

   commit 7f2ad8c26ad032800c049d0d6122c43410a5cbbc
   Author: John Doe <johndoe@gmail.com>
   Date:   Sun Aug 28 14:39:30 2016 +0300

        Initial commit

    1.txt | 1 +
    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
   ```

**Другие способы изменения истории**

Для изменения истории коммитов можно использовать такие команды как `git rebase` и `git filter-branch`, но они используются в гораздо более сложных случаях. Например, если вы хотите изменить коммит который был сделан несколько коммитов назад, то можете использовать интерактивный `rebase` - `git rebase -i`.

Подробнее об изменении истории в git можно прочесть [здесь](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8).

P.S. **Будьте осторожны**, используя этот приём, потому что `git commit --amend` по сути создает новый коммит, который включает изменения из коммита который вы меняете + добавленные изменения. Не правьте последний коммит, если вы его уже отправили в удаленный репозиторий.

Comment: <зануда> *меня[ть] SHA-1 коммита* невозможно. Git на самом деле откатывается на коммит назад и создаёт от предыдущего состояния новый коммит.</зануда>

Comment: Да, Вы правы, я не правильно выразился. Спасибо за поправку.

Comment: @Volen: Предлагаю улучшить ваш комментарий. Внесите больше ясности путем выполнения по шагам. К примеру добавили 1.txt , 2.txt . Далее что делать, если хочется добавить 3.txt, 4.txt ? Не просто указать комманду, а привести конкретные комманды в терминале прям тут в виде цитаты. Это позволит другим ищущим в гугле лучше понять суть решения

Comment: @sys_dev, спасибо за подсказку. Расписал ответ подробнее.

Comment: @Volen: Еще. Мне кажется, что нужно показать историю комитов до и после операции добавления забытого файла в существующий комит.

Comment: @sys_dev, добавил спасибо.

Comment: "просто передайте пустую строку вместо сообщения" - или можно явно  `--no-edit`

Answer (score 20):

> Важно: подразумевается, что ваш последний коммит ещё не был запушен,
>   потому что в командной работе не рекомендуется вносить изменения в
>   репозиторий через push -f. Об этом же был постскриптум @Volen.

Существует два способа, один уже описан выше @Volen, поэтому повторять не будут, второй вариант использует rebase. Что нужно сделать.

Есть коммит A, в который вы хотите добавить файл.

Вы создаёте коммит B, в который добавляете этот файл.

Потом вы даёте команду `git rebase -i HEAD~2` и у коммита B заменяете pick на squash (можно просто букву s подставить)

Т.е. исходно вам покажет что-то типа:

```
[ak@hostname testfolder]$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
pick 7921448 Commit A
pick 8a84e59 Commit B

# Rebase ce97832..8a84e59 onto ce97832
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
~
~
~
"~/testfolder/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo" 20L, 650C
```

Вам нужно влить коммит Б в А следующим образом:

```
pick 7921448 Commit A
s 8a84e59 Commit B
```

После сохранения будет окно в котором вам предложат выбрать имя нового, объединённого коммита:

```
Rebasing (2/2)
# This is a combination of 2 commits.
# The first commit's message is:

Commit A

# This is the 2nd commit message:

Commit B

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# HEAD detached at 7921448
# You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on 'ce97832'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD^1 <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   file2
#       new file:   file3
#
~
~
".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" 20L, 494C
```

Возможно, вам покажется, что способ через amend проще. Это действительно так.
Однако на базе rebase можно будет потом настолько широко модифицировать коммиты -- разбивать, объединять, переставлять местами -- что другие способы не идут ни в какое сравнение по функциональности.

Поэтому я люблю как раз показывать возможности с rebase именно с простых операций, а у вас как раз такая показательно простая.

PS Приводил пример из командной строки git, разумеется графические клиенты также умеют rebase -- например в SourceTree вы кликаете правое меню на предыдущем перед А коммитом и выбираете в контекстном меню пункт Rebase children  interactively.

Comment: В Git много команд на самом деле состоит из нескольких команд уровнями ниже. И этот "второй способ" скорее переусложняет процесс, хотя он полезен, если добавляемый файл уже закоммичен отдельным коммитом и это надо исправлять постфактум. А `git commit --amend` это почти что `git reset --soft HEAD~ && git add что-то && git commit`.

Answer (score 5):

Буду краток:

```
git add file.txt
git commit --amend
```

Если последний коммит перед этим уже за`push`или на сервер, то следующий `push` придется делать с `--force`, чтоб переписать.

Answer (score 1):

**Если на сервер еще не запушили**, то можно отменить последний коммит `git reset --soft HEAD^`, добавить недостающий файл с помощью `git add`, повторить коммит снова.

```
git reset --soft HEAD^ # отменить последний коммит
git add filename 
git status # видим зелёненькие файлики
git commit -m 'commit all files'
```

**Более кратко**:

**amend** cделает то же самое (добавит изменения в последний коммит):

```
git commit --amend
```