# Как удалить из локального коммита изменение в виде удаления папки с файлами?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Есть коммит состоящий из изменений пары файлов и удаления папки (не пустой).
Сейчас мне нужно изменить этот коммит перед push так, чтобы та папка все же осталась, изменения коснулись только кода

Я пробую

```
git rm --cached foldername
git rm -r --cached foldername
```

но получаю `did not match any files`

Как можно исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Нужно 'git checkout foldername" - и вся удалённая папка вернётся обратно как и была. Хотя стоп. Коммит состоящий -- то есть уже коммит сделан локально, так? Если есть локальный коммит, незапушенный -- то можно сделать rebase. Давайте определимся, что вы хотите: чтобы в первом коммите А было видно удаление папки, а во втором коммите Б было отменено удаление? Или вообще очистить коммит А от удаления папки?

Comment: Основы [git rebase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-rebase) есть много где в ответах на so, например [один из моих ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/475765/213987).

Comment: 1. очистить коммит А от удаления папки 2. папка не пустая

Comment: Лучше поставьте галку на ответ @D-side -- те, кто не умеет в rebase будут видеть простой способ, более внимательные всё равно прочитают все ответы в теме.

Comment: А, уже не надо менять галку ;) Я сегодня пробовал способ D-side для коммита, который был запушен неделю назад -- и попутно дописал ещё один способ восстановления, более очевидный, чем rebase. Тот самый, который испробовали -- отмотать историю на момент, когда файлы ещё были, сохранить их куда-нибудь, а потом отмотать на HEAD и подложить файлы, а потом объединить коммиты.

Comment: Не, давайте наверное переставим галку на ответ D-side. Лучше пусть этот способ будет наверху.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно просто вытащить эту папку обратно из предыдущего коммита:

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- foldername
```

Она будет уже в индексе, вам останется только заменить коммит-верхушку новым, в котором эта папка есть:

```
git commit --amend
```

---

*Стандартное предупреждение для читателей: `--amend` переписывает историю, не используйте на коммитах, которые уже публиковали в общие ветки. Вопрос этого и требует, просто подчёркиваю лишний раз, пока кому-нибудь не пришлось с грустным лицом [искать свои коммиты в рефлоге](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/232473/181100).*

Comment: Upvote за способ. Я бы даже рекомендовал топикстартеру галку поставить именно сюда. Если кто-то не умеет rebase -- то ваш способ быстр, прост, надёжен. Если кто-то осваивает rebase -- см. в мой туториал.

Comment: Надо же... сегодня попробовал этот способ на реальном проекте и не сработало (указывал SHA ID коммита где-то далеко-далеко), выдавало сообщение, что нет такого пути. ;( Плюс всё равно не получилось бы: все эти изменения были давно запушены. Но зато я думал, как проделать подобный финт и придумал ещё один способ.

Comment: @AK если это был коммит, **в котором** удалялась эта папка, то да, в этом коммите этого пути уже нет. В том, что перед ним, должен быть. Так что не знаю, что у вас могло не получиться.

Answer (score 2):

Делается это проще всего через интерактивный rebase.

> Внимание! Сначала рекомендуется сделать полную копию всей папки и
>   файлов, чтобы была возможность предварительно проделать изменения на
>   копии.

Промоделируем ситуацию.

У нас есть какой-то репозиторий:

```
[www]$ cd ~
[~]$ mkdir test && cd test && git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ak/test/.git/
[test]$ touch 123.txt
[test]$ git add .
[test]$ git commit -m "123.txt"
[master (root-commit) 6054429] 123.txt
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 123.txt
[test]$ mkdir folder
[test]$ touch folder/1.txt
[test]$ touch folder/2.txt
[test]$ touch aaa.txt
[test]$ git add .
[test]$ git commit -m "Create some folder and files"
[master c0b67ad] Create some folder and files
 3 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 aaa.txt
 create mode 100644 folder/1.txt
 create mode 100644 folder/2.txt
[test]$
```

Во время активной разработки мы сделали коммит Temp commit, который нам казался правильным. Он содержит удаление папки и добавление какого-то файла:

```
[test]$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
[test]$ git rm -r folder/
rm 'folder/1.txt'
rm 'folder/2.txt'
[test]$ touch bbb.txt
[test]$ git add -A
[test]$ git commit -m "Temp commit"
[master 021ec06] Temp commit
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename folder/1.txt => bbb.txt (100%)
 delete mode 100644 folder/2.txt
[test]$
```

И потом мы решили убрать из этого коммита удаление папки.

Входим в режим интерактивного rebase:

```
[test]$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
pick c0b67ad Create some folder and files
pick 021ec06 Temp commit

# Rebase 6054429..021ec06 onto 6054429
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
~
~
~
"~/test/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo" 20L, 673C
```

Нам нужно заменить строку `pick 021ec06 Temp commit` на `e 021ec06 Temp commit` и выйти с сохранением. (Основы редактирования в vi не рассматриваются, но я бы сделал как `j 4x i e ESC :wq`).

Мы остановились на редактировании коммита:

```
[test]$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
Stopped at 021ec06... Temp commit
You can amend the commit now, with

        git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

        git rebase --continue

[test]$
```

Теперь мы должны сделать следующие операции:

```
[test]$ git reset HEAD~
Unstaged changes after reset:
D       folder/1.txt
D       folder/2.txt
```

Мы просто возвращаем из stage area обратно.

Посмотрите что мы получилось:

```
[test]$ git status
# HEAD detached at c0b67ad
# You are currently splitting a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '6054429'.
#   (Once your working directory is clean, run "git rebase --continue")
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    folder/1.txt
#       deleted:    folder/2.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       bbb.txt
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
[test]$
```

Мы можем теперь добавить только то в коммит, что хотим и не добавлять то, что не хотим (удаление папки):

```
[test]$ git add bbb.txt
[test]$ git commit -m "New commit"
[detached HEAD 666dc98] New commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bbb.txt
```

Удаление папки осталось:

```
[test]$ git status
# HEAD detached from c0b67ad
# You are currently splitting a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '6054429'.
#   (Once your working directory is clean, run "git rebase --continue")
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    folder/1.txt
#       deleted:    folder/2.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
[test]$
```

Но оно не входит ни в какие коммиты. Мы даём команду на продолжение rebase и видим, что нужно положить на stash удаление:

```
[test]$ git rebase --continue
folder/1.txt: needs update
folder/2.txt: needs update
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
[test]$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on (no branch): 666dc98 New commit
HEAD is now at 666dc98 New commit
[test]$ git status
# HEAD detached from c0b67ad
# You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '6054429'.
#   (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
#   (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
[test]$ git rebase --continue
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
[test]$
```

В принципе, удаление папки нам не нужно, чистим карман:

```
[test]$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on (no branch): 666dc98 New commit
[test]$ git stash drop
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (73ad2a9ff3b4304a5106a259cb14135eaa9a711c)
[test]$
```

И смотрим историю:

```
[test]$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

[test]$ git log
commit 666dc983ae2ecf894e76c83d5c061a9449d672f4
Author: ak at server <ak@company.ru>
Date:   Fri Dec 1 21:23:02 2017 +0300

    New commit

commit c0b67ad5e1f72536891e8c23a72746c83e103e3c
Author: ak at server-43 <ak@company.ru>
Date:   Fri Dec 1 21:08:11 2017 +0300

    Create some folder and files

commit 605442916d9a5757f2d4ad5847205a75711c9cab
Author: ak at server-43 <ak@company.ru>
Date:   Fri Dec 1 21:06:38 2017 +0300

    123.txt
[test]$
```

Всё, как нам и надо было:

```
[test]$ git show HEAD
commit 666dc983ae2ecf894e76c83d5c061a9449d672f4
Author: ak at server-43 <ak@company.ru>
Date:   Fri Dec 1 21:23:02 2017 +0300

    New commit

diff --git a/bbb.txt b/bbb.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
[test]$
```

---

Альтернативный способ для тех, кто будет читать тему -- это тот способ, который [кратко описывал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752463/213987) топикстартер + дополнительный пункт с объединением коммитов в один.

1. Проверить, что нет незакоммиченных изменений (чтобы потом не было мучительно больно, когда после `reset --hard` пропадут файлы)
2. Становимся на коммит ПЕРЕД коммитом, когда были удалены файлы: `git reset -- hard HEAD~5`
3. Получаем состояние, в котором файлы не были удалены. Сохраняем их в какую-нибудь директорию вне гита.
4. Возвращаемся назад `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` (тут более логично смотреть reflog, написано из расчёта, что больше никаких команд не делали. мы понимаем, что есть незапушенные коммиты и их можно потерять, если что-то сделать неаккуратно)
5. Подкладываем папку на место и коммитим её.
6. При необходимости объединяем (squash) два идущих подряд коммита (первый - - с удалением папки, второй -- с её добавлением) Пример можно посмотреть в [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559726/213987).

Comment: *Сначала рекомендуется сделать полную копию всей папки и файлов* -- зачем такая тяжёлая артиллерия? Оставить на исходном месте веточку и не трогать её в течение всего процесса.

Comment: @D-side Я ставлю на всякий случай подобные предупреждения для того, чтобы те, кто только осваивают операции rebase имели возможность потренироваться, либо если потренировавшись на копии допустили промах на оригинале и не пришлось читать рефлог. Так проще при изучении. Сам я, разумеется, во время rebase резервных копий не делаю, потому что уже давно натренировался и понимаю, что делаю и для чего.

Comment: Второй способ какой-то жутковатый. Зачем делать `reset --hard` только затем, чтобы получить в рабочем дереве состояние на указанный коммит, если то же самое делает `checkout`, но не трогая положение ветки?

Comment: не ясно, как простыня выше может быть "проще всего" двух простых команд из D-side ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему откатом `git reset --hard HEAD^` и повторным внесением изменений с комитом в эту ветку. 
Решение так себе, но рабочее. Уверен, есть что-то куда более правильное.