# Очистить историю коммитов git

Tags: git

История коммитов выглядит след образом:
Commit1
CommitFIX
Commit2
Commit3

Как убрать из истории CommitFIX, чтобы его правки были в Commit1?

Comment: [git rebase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559726/213987). Просто влейте коммит CommitFIX (коммит B в терминах ответа по ссылке) в Commit1 (A)

Comment: @AK Если сделать rebase старых коммитов у себя локально, они отправятся через git push в remote?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/751168/178576

Comment: @jin90 если под "старых" подразумевается "запушенных" то только через push --force со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения проблем такого рода используеться [интерактивный вариант](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) комманды `git rebase`.

1. Переключаемся на `Commit3`

   ```
   git checkout Commit3
   ```
2. Запускаем интерактивный `git rebase`

   ```
   git rebase -i HEAD~4
   ```
3. Запуститься среда для редактирования скрипта изменения истории. Используйте `squash` чтобы слить коммиты.

   ```
   pick Commit1
   squash CommitFIX
   pick Commit2
   pick Commit3

   # Rebase 710f0f8..a5f4a0d onto 710f0f8
   #
   # Commands:
   #  p, pick = use commit
   #  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
   #  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
   #  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
   #  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
   #  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
   #
   # These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
   #
   # If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
   #
   # However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
   #
   # Note that empty commits are commented out
   ```
4. Сохраните файл и выйдете из него для запуска скрипта
5. Проверьте историю, она будет успешно изменена

P.S. **Будьте осторожны**, используя этот приём, потому что `git rebase` по сути создает новые коммиты. Не изменяйте историю, если вы уже отправили изменения в удаленный репозиторий.