# Как схлопнуть историю только для части файлов в репозитории, например, для изображений?

Tags: git

Как схлопнуть историю только для части файлов в репозитории, например, для изображений и потом почистить мусор?

- Имеется ввиду, существует ли способ, годный для постоянного использования, а не для одного раза. Пытаемся как-то ужить вместе в одном репозитории изменения изображений и историю кода. Дело в том, что изображения могут меняться в пределах развития очередной версии, но хочется сохранять в итоге только утверждённые версии изображений, а все промежуточные вынужденные сохранения удалить.

Comment: например: 1. [удалите эти файлы из истории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/669670/178576). 2. [добавьте эти файлы в первый коммит](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7295511/4827341).

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Наверное, если нет способа проще, то надо менять подход.

Comment: так вам нужен **правильный подход**. правильный подход банален до такой степени, что повторять его в миллионный раз уже, наверно, не стоит: программа git предназначена для управления версиями **текстовых** файлов. уживайтесь с этой банальностью!

Comment: Мы не нашли банального подхода, чтобы иметь возможность совместить в одном репозитории и текст и бинарные файлы. Ну вот как? Мы не можем отдельно всё вести, и как не старайся сохранять в репозитории только самую последнюю препоследнюю версию картинки, которая точно самая последняя — всё рано потом приходится сохранять ещё несколько ну вот точно уже последних версии картинок. И т. к. я не один, то надо эту последнюю версию картинки доставить другим, картинка должна быть среди кода.. И проще  её в репозитории передать, но это просто неразумная трата места.

Comment: Зачем же? Можно прекрасно держать отедельное хранилище файлов, а в репозитории держать ссылки на конкретный файл конкретной версии. Так, например, в Fedora хранятся оригинальные тарболы пакетов, которые потом собираются уже в инфраструктуре Fedora, и на выходе мы получаем бинарные пакеты Fedora.

Comment: [для «бедных» — lfs, для «умных» — annex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39337586/4827341). выбирайте.

Answer (score 0):

> существует ли способ, годный для постоянного использования, а не для одного раза

увы, для того, чтобы править историю хранилища на постоянной основе, нет иного способа кроме как сменить «основу»: просто вынести бинарные файлы из хранилища (которое к тому же совсем не предназначено для этого). хранить их можно отдельно, либо просто в каталоге (и сохранять ссылки на эти файлы), либо воспользоваться готовыми решениями: [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com) или [git-annex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git-annex) ([отличия между ними, на англ.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39337586/4827341)).

для однократной (или редкой) же правки удалите файлы из одних коммитов и добавьте в нужные. см., например: [Как исключить файлы из коммита, чтобы включить их в другой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/475765/178576)

Answer (score 0):

```
# клонируем репозиторий в соседний каталог
git clone --no-local . ../clonerepo/

# отправляем картинки в отдельную ветку
git checkout --orphan images
git reset
git add "*.jpg"
git commit -m "Add Images"

# переходим в свежий клон
cd ../clonerepo
# чистим репо от картинок
git filter-repo --path-glob "*.jpg" --invert-paths --partial
# проверим что файлы исчезли
git log --oneline --name-status -- "*.jpg"

# добавляем последнюю версию картинок
git pull origin images --allow-unrelated-histories

# можно отправить пересобранную ветку обратно
git push --force
# либо поправить origin и продолжить работу уже в этом репозитории.
```